# Magento 1 migrate to Magento 2 process

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I just have a question about the migration process from M1 to M2.

1. Run the data migration tool.
2. Test thoroughly on the new M2 store
3. Run the incremental migration tool.
4. Switch to new M2 store.

Can **orders, products, customers be added** at #2 on the new M2 store?

Will it screw up the incremental migration tool if that is done?

This is a big question because client will likely want to test thoroughly and count span a couple / few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data migration tool brings in your orders, products and customer data. So you will have real data to test with yes.

The incremental data will only be bringing in new/updated data. The following is the manner in which my firm manages the data migration.

1) We clone the magento 1 live database (m1_live) to an offline database for migrating data (m1_offline). We then run the data migration tool against m1_offline and not m1_live.

2) Develop the Magento 2 store/test etc until ready for production.

3) For final migration, we backup Magento2 database and put Magento 1 into maintenance, clone the database to m1_offline. Run the incremental migration against m1_offline. At this point no one ever touches the Magento 1 database/backend/frontend again.

4) Launch Magento2 store.

Comment: At step 2 of your process is it okay to add new product attributes and products?

Comment: Yes, generally you won't have any issues adding new products or attributes provided you don't duplicate the SKUs or attribute Ids in the M1 database. I would also recommend, before you run test orders on the M2 site to backup the database, then run your test orders and then revert to the previous m2 backup before the orders were placed. The reason is the incremental id's will be out of sync from the M1 database and sometimes it causes issues on the incremental migration on step 3.

Answer (score 1):

**You will have some issue in Run the incremental migration tool.**

As you will place once changes during   testing.

My Suggestion to you,  donot use step3.

Steps Should like that:

- Gather all process  which you have done so far.
- Make website for few hours.
- Take latest M1  database, run  Data migration process from begin
- Run all  process from your note

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this process step-by-step

Handle extensions' compatibility issues, check that functionality works on the sample data. Handle major functionality issues and theme conflicts

Wipe the database (remove the sample data)

Run the Magento migration tool

Gather a list of errors which are related to DB structure difference

Basing on the error list and the DB difference analysis, give additional handling:
- to input DB constraints and FK violations
- to DB structure changes
- to data-level changes (e.g. the extensions' logic has been adjusted so the data should - be transformed to correspond it)
- to data relation adjustments
... 
Prooflink https://m1-to-m2-migration.com/how-to-upgrade#transfer-data